# Placing gas stations

Tags: algorithm

This is similar to a vertex cover problem but it will be smaller than a vertex cover. Think of this problem as you have a map and the vertices are cities and the edges are the roads from one city to another. Each edge has a weight that represents how long it is. There is a law required that within `k` miles of a city there must exist a gas station.

I want to figure out how many gas stations to place so that I can minimize the number of stations to save money. What is a good way to approach this? I was thinking of getting a vertex cover first and start from a city, go to any city that is connected and keep doing it until I get `k` and remove stations from every city I go except the first one. Would that be a good approach to this problem?

Comment: So, `k` is fixed, or each city has a `k` value?

Comment: Can gas stations be placed in the middle of roads?  For example if `k=3` and there is a road of length `5` can I put a gas station in the middle of the road and cover both cities?

Comment: `k` is a predetermined number but it's fixed for all cities. And no gas stations can only be placed in a city.